# Is it safe to use a Node.js request (req) as key to a WeakMap

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to store information along with a Node.js request (`IncomingMessage`). I'd like to do it with a WeakMap like this:

```js
const infoByRequest = new WeakMap()

// somewhere in the request handler

const setInfo = (req, info) => {
  infoByRequest.set(req, info)
}

const getInfo = (req) => {
  return infoByRequest.get(req)
}
```

Is this safe? I was wondering if the req object instance eventually gets reused and thus may not work as expected.

Comment: Why do you want to do that, the request object only gets used while you handle it, why would you want to preserve it along with others? Maybe look into a message queue like RabbitMQ

Comment: How are these function used ? Are they callback function passed to express' `app.get(..)` or `app.post(..)`, etc. ? If that is the case, `req` from `setInfo` will not be the same object as `req` from `getInfo` (`infoByRequest.get(req)` will always return `undefined`)

Comment: It is used inside a handler (actually it is a Next.js page getInitialProps) and i expect the info only to be consistent inside the very same handler invokation

Comment: I can not see a meaningful way to do that. Using a weak map means that your intentions are that info vanishes when the request is done, hence why you don't simply inject info inside req and use it upward in the handler chain? Can you explain better your intended use?

Comment: @Newbie that is correct. The motivatioj is to avoid poluting the req object + to avoid Typescript hassle with extending types.

Comment: I'm pretty sure they don't get reused (pooled), as many middlewares already *do* store context stuff on the request objects.

Comment: Everybody else just adds properties to the `req` object to solve this type of issue as it is fairly core to middleware design.  If you REALLY want to avoid any possible name conflict, then you can use a Symbol as the property name, but you will have to share the Symbol with anyone who plans to use it.  But, you were already thinking of sharing the weakMap so it appears you can share a Symbol instead.

Comment: Looking for a solution to put an authentication data to request and avoid pollution of a request object and make it easy to work with types as well I came out to the same idea as you. It would be great if you can share some experience of using this in a real app. Are there any hidden gotchas?

Answer (score 2):

> Is it safe to use a Node.js request (req) as key to a WeakMap

Yes, it is safe.  `req` objects are not reused/recycled.  They are garbage collected when no longer in use just like other objects.

---

Everybody else just adds properties to the `req` object to solve this type of issue as it is fairly core to the middleware design.  You see middleware built-into Express doing this very thing.

If you REALLY want to avoid any possible name conflict, then you can use a `Symbol` as the property name, but you will have to share the `Symbol` with anyone who plans to use it. But, you were already thinking of sharing the `weakMap` so it appears you can share a `Symbol` instead.

```
// create symbol upon startup
const mwSymbol = Symbol("myMiddlewareTag");

// middleware sets some data on the req object using the symbol
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    req[mwSymbol] = someData;
    next();
});

// request handler later accessing the same data
app.get((req, res) => {
    let data = req[mwSymbol];
    // do something with data
    req.send(...);
});
```

Because Symbols are guaranteed unique and do not ever collide with strings (they are essentially separate namespaces), you're guaranteed a unique property accessor.  This is one of the core things Symbols were introduced into the language to be used for.

---

One advantage of the weakMap over the Symbol would be privacy.  If you didn't want anyone to be able to enumerate the properties of the `req` object and find your symbol, then the weakMap could offer better privacy.

Comment: Just to add another potential benefit of this, it makes it easier to work with express and TypeScript, as you can use the WeakMap value as a 'context' which can be more easily  typed than the raw `req` object.